# Traversing a general tree recursively in depth-first order

Tags: c, recursion, tree, binary-tree, depth-first-search

I am asked to implement a recursive function for traversing a general tree (first child, next sibling notation) and a binary tree in depth-first order.

The function should print the node when it last visits it.   For example, for the tree below, the nodes should be printed in the following order.
I think I have done the function for the binary tree but I could not do the general one:

Here is my code for the binary tree:

```
void PostOrder(node* root) {
    if (root == NULL)
        return;
    else { 
          PostOrder(root->left); 
          PostOrder(root->right);
          printf(‘%c’, root->key); 
    } 
}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Why don't you use `DFS`?

Comment: How is the general one defined? does a node have an array of children? What did you try for the general case? Details, please

Comment: each node has two pointers ! the first one points to the first child and the other one points to the next sibling (for the general tree). Thank you

Comment: Can you give a tree where the algorithm should print a different order?

Comment: a as a root. points to its first child b. This first child (b) points to the next sibling c. b points to its first child (d)->(e)->(f)
c points to its first child (g). (g) points to its first child (h)->(i). It is very difficult to draw it using language. thank you

Comment: Above code would print: f e d g c b a.  What should it print?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like it's a typical "general tree represented as binary tree" with two pointers: first child, and next sibling.  We can draw the tree as a standard binary tree, with each child having a down-leading arrow and a right-leading arrow.

I think the tree described in your comment looks like this:

```
a
|
V
b ------------> c
|               |
V               V
d --> e --> f   g
                |
                V
                h --> i
```

You want, at each node of the tree, to:

1. Print all the descendants first, by processing the first child (follow the down arrow).
2. Then print the node's value
3. Then process the siblings (follow the right arrow).

Applying this to the tree above, we get:

```
GeneralTreePostOrder(a) ->
    GeneralTreePostOrder(b) ->   # Follow child pointer
        GeneralTreePostOrder(d) ->   # Follow child pointer
            # No children
            print d
            GeneralTreePostOrder(e) ->   # Follow sibling pointer
                 # No children
                 print e
                 GeneralTreePostOrder(f) ->   # Follow sibling pointer
                     # No children
                     print f
                     # No more siblings
        print b
        GeneralTreePostOrder(c) ->   # Follow sibling pointer
```

Etc., which prints `d e f h i g c a`.

Writing a new function for the general tree (N.B. `printf` should use a double-quoted format string):

```
void GeneralTreePostOrder (node* root) {
    if (root == NULL)
        return;
    else {
         GeneralTreePostOrder (root->left); // Process children
         printf ("%c", root->key); 
         GeneralTreePostOrder (root->right); // Process siblings
    } 
}
```

Comment: The traversal you propose here is in-order traversal, not post-order. The name of the function should reflect that, otherwise it is misleading.